# How to evaluate function for input array [matlab]

Tags: matlab, vectorization

Suppose I have a function `func.m` in matlab

```
  function [sum] = func(x)
      d = length(x);
      sum = 0;
      for i = 1:d
        sum = sum + x(i)^2;
    end
  end
```

and two vectors defined as

```
  x1 = 1:10;
  x2 = 1:10;
```

How can I evaluate the function values `for each [x1[i] x2[i]] for i = 1:10` and store the result in vector without using for loop.

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're trying to do. Please clarify

Comment: @Italy What I want is this z[1] = func([x1[1] x2[1]]), z[2] = func([x1[2] x2[2]]), ... z[10] = func([x1[10] x2[10]])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to create a matrix `M` where each column is a pair of parameters you want to send to the function.

e.g.:

```
>> x1 = 1:10
>> x2 = 1:10

x1 =

     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10


x2 =

     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10

>> M =[x1;x2]

M =

     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
```

Then we create a cell array that contains the parameter pairs (`M`'s columns):

```
>> M2 = num2cell(M, 1)

M2 = 

    [2x1 double]    [2x1 double]    [2x1 double]    [2x1 double]    [2x1 double]    [2x1 double]    [2x1 double]    [2x1 double]    [2x1 double]    [2x1 double]
```

Which gives us such a cell array:

```
>> M2{1}

ans =

     1
     1

>> M2{3}

ans =

     3
     3
```

Now you want to call [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) with the cell array and the required function.

e.g. with the default `sum` function:

```
>> cellfun(@sum, M2)

ans =

     2     4     6     8    10    12    14    16    18    20
```

Or with your `func`:

```
>> cellfun(@func, M2)

ans =

     2     8    18    32    50    72    98   128   162   200
```

---

BTW, your function `func` is simply the l2 [`norm`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/norm.html) squared, that already exists in matlab:

```
>> cellfun(@norm, M2) .^ 2

ans =

    2.0000    8.0000   18.0000   32.0000   50.0000   72.0000   98.0000  128.0000  162.0000  200.0000
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you've asked for ways to vectorize your code, here are some suggestions. Firstly, I'd start off by updating the function definition of `func.m`.

```
function s = func(x)
    s = sum(x.^2); % An alternate way is to do: s = diag(x'*x)';
end
```

Secondly, it isn't very clear as to what you're trying to do in the second part. Assuming you have two **row vectors** x1 and x2, and want to evaluate the function for both vectors simultaneously, then you can perform:

```
s = func([x1; x2]') % and you will have s(1) and s(2) for the vectors.
```

If you want to do it *between* the vectors, and hence need 10 different `func` values, do:

```
s = func([x1; x2]) % and s is then a 1 x 10 array.
```

However, as a piece of advice, I would recommend you to stick to one notation of vectors. Usually MATLAB by default uses column major, in that most functions execute along each column, if a matrix is used as the argument. That's why in the `func.m` I've described above, if you pass in a matrix, the default behaviour is to evaluate `func.m` along each column.

Comment: I want `s` to be vector, with your above code `s` is a scaler.

Comment: I'm not sure if you executed my code or read the answer fully, the second example usage gives you a vector of 10 elements, in a lot simpler way than creating cells for such a trivial task.

You get s(1) as the func evaluated for x1(1) and x2(1), s(2) at the next two points and so on.